# Prevent IIS Rscycle/Restart while adding new Binding

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am adding new bindings in IIS from my Asp.net application but whenever I add a new binding from my application then my application restarts and throws User to Login Page. The site is running on IIS 7, running ASP.NET 4.6 and is configured to run in integrated mode and I'm using web forms.

I also tried AppPool settings "Disable Recycling for Configuration Change" set to "True" but no success.

How to prevent this IIS recycling while adding a new binding? is there any solution for this?

Comment: Any changes will cause an app pool recycle.

Comment: @DingPeng Can't I see my changes without IIS recycle, I do not want to expire my user session who is creating subdomain within my application and who must see changes without logout.

Comment: If you add a new binding, the app pool will recycle.